# C++20 template lambda: how to specify template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

Let's say I have a C++20 template lambda:

```cpp
auto foo = []<bool arg>() {
    if constexpr(arg)
        ...
    else
        ...
};
```

But how do I call it? I can't seem to find a description of the syntax. I tried the usual `foo<true>();` and `template foo<true>();`, neither of which gcc seems to like.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```cpp
foo.template operator()<true>();
```

is the correct syntax. Try it on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/PhYba9)

The reason for this strange syntax is because:

- `foo` is a generic lambda which implements a [`template<bool> operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::operator.28.29.28params.29) method.
- `foo.operator()<true>()` would interpret `<` as a comparison operator.

If you want a *slightly* more readable syntax, try using a [`std::bool_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant#Helper_templates):

```cpp
auto foo = []<bool arg>(std::bool_constant<arg>) {
    ...
};

foo(std::bool_constant<true>{});
```

Try it on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/3WdPE1)

Comment: This suggests that the idiomatic way of using this language feature is somewhat different from this scenario :)

Comment: @lubgr agreed, it's more idiomatic when explicit template parameters on lambdas are deduced from the function arguments.

Comment: @lubgr: The point of the feature is to allow deduction of template parameter types from patterns in function arguments (being able to do `[]<class T>(std::vector<T> const &vt)`), not to pass template arguments directly to the function.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts! While I did read though that page I didn't quite figure out that this is how one would call it.

Comment: Disgusting :-p. But it works. Never would have figured this out on my own, so THANK YOU!!!